# Barcode printing with Toshiba B-SA4T

Tags: barcode

I have a problem to print a barcode with the Toshiba label printer because I haven't found the correct syntax creating that.

Here is what I have tried to but printer always gives error from XB00 row

{C|}

{PC01;0000,0020,1,1,A,00,B=01000035|}

{XB00;0000,0280,9,3,04,0,0080,000,0,00,B=01000035|}

{XS;I,0001,0002C2200|}

Does anyone have an example of how that XB row should build? I have some manual, but there is only that barcode can be configured, but there isn't told how.